# VS2010 fatal Error LNK1318, mspdbsrv.exe used up it's 4GB memory

Tags: visual-studio-2010

We have a large project, recently we've merged two dll into one for some reason. Then we got an Error LNK1318 while linking, and mspdbsrv.exe reached 4063MB of max memory usage,then linker report  Fatal Error LNK1318  Unexpected PDB Error, OK(0)

Answer (score 1):

mspdbsrv.exe is the utility program that is launched behind the scenes to create PDB symbols used for debugging your code.

I've read anecdotal reports regarding earlier versions of Visual Studio (e.g., 2005) that this little process has been a source of pain for before in the past, but I haven't run into any with daily dev work in 2010.

It sounds to me like you've built up a cache of PDB files that it's trying to combine into one at build time. Only problem is, that produces a file that's 4 GB (!!) in size. I'd delete all of the temporary files associated with your project and kill the mspdbsrv.exe process (or restart the computer), and then try building again. You might also want to turn off [incremental builds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691231.aspx), which rebuild only the information that has changed since the last build. That'll force a full rebuild, which should produce a PDB file without any extra bloat.

Comment: thankyou,it works...mspdbsrv.exe used 3700+ mb memory ,and generate a 238MB pdb file. Now the only problem is what will happen if the project keep on growing..